# InvokeMember("click") always opens a new window and navigates to about:blank#

Tags: c#, hyperlink, click, browser, invokemember

I am trying to write a code that automatically clicks a link on a webpage by looking for the `<a>` element and using `InvokeMember("click")`. Here's what I've got so far:

```
HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(fetchRandom(filetxt.Text));
                CookieContainer cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
                webRequest.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
                webRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
                //webRequest.Proxy = new WebProxy(host, port);

                HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
                Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();

                if (!webBrowser1.IsDisposed)
                {
                    webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
                    webBrowser1.DocumentStream = receiveStream;
                    Delay(delayint);

                    if (!webBrowser1.IsDisposed)
                    {

                        HtmlElementCollection links = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a");

                        //int count = 0;
                        foreach (HtmlElement link in links)
                        {

                        }

                        Delay(delayint);
                    }
                }

                HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(fetchRandom(filetxt.Text));
                CookieContainer cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
                webRequest.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
                webRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
                //webRequest.Proxy = new WebProxy(host, port);

                HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
                Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();

                if (!webBrowser1.IsDisposed)
                {
                    webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
                    webBrowser1.DocumentStream = receiveStream;
                    Delay(delayint);

                    if (!webBrowser1.IsDisposed)
                    {

                        HtmlElementCollection links = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a");

                        int count = 0;
                        foreach (HtmlElement link in links)
                        {
                            if (count == 0)
                            {
                                 link.InvokeMember("click");
                                 count = count + 1
                            }
                        }

                        Delay(delayint);
                    }
                }
```

It's doing a great job at finding all the `<a>` elements and saving each individual one. The problem is that it opens every link it "clicks" in a new window, and it always navigates to **about:blank#** including the #. Manually clicking the links in the webBrowser in the form also does this. Clicking the same link is Chrome does not.

How do I get it to not open the link in a new window, but always open it in `webBrowser1` and get it to navigate to the right URL?

This is an example of a webpage I've tried it on:

```
<a href="#" onclick="redirect('51865fd774d8f419270045', '7020'); return false;" target="_blank" class="headline">
            Link            </a>
```

Also, the `int count` is going to be used later on.

Comment: ^ have you typed the example link correctly? I think it's not shown right.

Comment: Yes I am sure that the link correct. I think it is a javascript thingie..